# Speex for Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, speex

Try as I might I can't find a Speex implementation for Windows Phone 7. I'd rather not attempt to port it to C# myself if it's already been done. Can anyone point me toward a WP7 implementation of Speex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a Silverlight implementation of Speex [here](http://nspeex.codeplex.com/), it should work also on WP7.

Comment: Ah my mistake, there is a C# version of Speex 1.xx in there. Thanks.